# Using regex to match String to name in external file

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program that is supposed to detect whether a type name is contained within an external file. For example, if a string is equal to "anitasugarland" and the external file contains the name "ANITA" then is there any way to confirm if there is a name match? The problem I'm having is if I just use Java's "startsWith" then it matches on other names like "An" or other names. As you can see this can cause inaccuracies. So is there a way using regex or word boundaries to check if a first name in the string matches the one in the external file? As of now this really has me stumped. If someone could take a look at this or provide a possible solution I would very much appreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: Given the string "anitasugarland", how would the program tell that it should match "anita" but not "an"?  How could it know how much of the string is the first name?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm not sure if this is even possible. That's why I thought I would ask anyway.

Comment: So, you need to think of some way of telling your program that "anita" is a name, but "an" isn't.  Could you use an external file of acceptable names, or something like that?